# How to Increment unsigned int by 1 using bit-shifting & logical opr only?

Tags: language-agnostic, bit-shift

I have a question in my assignment / project that adds 1 to an unsigned integer only using *bit-shifting* and *logical operators*. There shouldn't be any "+", "-", "*", or "/" symbols in the function.

I am trying from last days but no success yet. So far I've tried the following:

```
int A = (((B&C)<<1)^(B^C))
```

Can anybody help me to solve this.?

You can help me in any programming language.

Comment: *Three* languages, and you're telling us this isn't homework?!

Comment: If we can help in *any* language, use the [language-agnostic] tag, not as many random popular tags as you can think of.

Comment: Edd you have the power to retag question. :]

Comment: @KerrekSB, this **is** a homework. I had a totally same HW when I was at the school... otherwise, I could do it then. :D

Comment: @KubaWyrostek I already had :p I was just venting...

Comment: @Edd, I tried this **int A = (((B&C)<<1)^(B^C))**. But issue is i couldn't found a way to calculate without bitwise operators. I can't use bitwise opr in my solution.

Comment: You should explicitely state which operations *are* allowed.

Comment: The classification of operators may be language-specific, but for example in C the "bitwise operators" are unary `~` and binary `<<, >>, &, ^, |`. The "logical operators" are unary `!` and binary `&&, ||`. The "bitwise shift" operators are just `<<` and `>>`.

Comment: If only `!`, `&&`, `||`, `<<` and `>>` are allowed, then it's impossible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
unsigned int i = ...;
unsigned int mask = 1;
while (i & mask)
{
    i &= ~mask;
    mask <<= 1;
}
i |= mask;
```

Comment: I mention in question to use only **bit-shifting** and **logical operators**

Comment: @MicroEyes so you don't like the while loop or what? If you have e.g. 32 bit ints, you can of course unroll the loop if you want.

Answer (score 8):

Java:

```
public static int inc(int i){
        if ((i & 1) == 0)
            return i | 1;
        else 
            return inc(i>>1)<<1;
    }
```

P.S. while loop variant by [henrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148897/henrik) is obviously faster

Comment: Sir, I mention in question to use only **bit-shifting** and **logical operators**

Comment: Where do I break this rule? I can not check conditions?

Comment: You use `|`, which by the questioner's definition is neither a bit-shift operator nor a logical operator.

Comment: According to a comment by the questioner, "i couldn't found a way to calculate without bitwise operators. I can't use bitwise opr in my solution". So `^` is also forbidden. This may (as Henrik says) make it impossible. Or perhaps just impossible without writing something of the order of UINT_MAX lines of code.

Answer (score 5):

Try this one:

```
int n = 3;
n = abs(~n);
std::cout << n;
```

`~n = -(n+1)` [ `~` is for bitwise complement ]. `(n + 1)` is due to addition of 1 in 2’s complement conversion.

To get `(x + 1)` apply negation once again. So, the final expression becomes `abs(~x)`.

Comment: I upvoted because it's interesting but it violates the rules of the question in that the negation operator is used.

Comment: Oh, i missed it, BTW, you can replace this negation operator with `abs()` like this:
`int n = 3;
n = abs(~n);
std::cout << n;`
I'll update my answer, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Logic to inrement a number without using arithmetic operators(`+, -. * and /`)

```
unsinged int no = 3; //actual number
unsigned int one = 1;
unsigned int ans = 0;
unsigned int carry = 0;
unsigned int prev_ans = 0;
unsigned int prev_carry = 0;

ans = no ^ one;
carry = no & one;

while (carry != 0)
{
   carry <<= 1;

   prev_ans = ans;
   prev_carry = carry;

   ans = prev_ans ^ prev_carry;
   carry = prev_ans & prev_carry;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google for **Full Adder** and try to implement one.

Answer (score -3):

This is too easy, for example in Haskell:

```
data Unsigned = Zero | Succ Unsigned
increment :: Unsigned -> Unsigned
increment u = Succ u
```

No bitwise or arithmetic operators, no operators at all!